# Magento 2 How to create a dynamically populated select field in admin UI component form?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, uicomponent, adminform

Is there a way to populate a select dropdown field with the values of what is selected in another multiselect dropdown field on the same page and fieldset? This is in regards to the ui component form in adminhtml.

Essentially this is what I require: In an admin UI component form, say product create form or customer create form, I want one multiselect dropdown field to have for example all countries in the world. I also want a single select dropdown field (normal dropdown), whose values are populated from the countries I selected from the previous fields. So if I select only five countries in the first multiselect dropdown, I want only those five to be the options of the second select dropdown.

Comment: Can you please give example or screenshot what you want actually here?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, I added an example to my question, thank you!